# Remove Aptana Rubles folder

Tags: aptana-studio

When I start Aptana Studio 3 in my Ubuntu 11.10, it automatically creates a folder named "Aptana Rubles" at ~/Documents. How to configure to remove it permanently? I tried to find an option in Preferences of Aptana but I don't see anything related.
If I can't remove, how to move it to another place?

I tried this but it still create the "Aptana Rubles" at ~/Documents
http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+User+Bundle+Directory

Edit: my AptanaStudio3.ini

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

-Dstudio.rubleUserLocation="/home/hieund/Programs/Aptana Studio 3/Aptana Rubles"
-Daptana.ruble.user.location="/home/hieund/Programs/Aptana Studio 3/Aptana Rubles"

-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.log.size.max=10000
-Declipse.log.backup.max=5
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you followed the correct instructions for your Aptana version? Does it maybe work with the other variant? Are you sure you passed these arguments correctly? You could try specifying other arguments (e.g. workspace location) and see if they are received correctly by the application.

Comment: This perfectly works for me, however (1) I use only Dstudio.rubleUserLocation, (2) I don't use quotes (maybe space causes this), (3) the entry is last one in the ini file, (4) the folder already exists before I run aptana. You also need to follow their rules:1. The directory must exist
2. The directory must be writable
3. The directory must be readable

Comment: I had this same problem with Aptana Studio Plugin for Eclipse on Mac OS X.  The solution was to open up the Eclipse.app contents, and then edit the eclipse.ini file within by adding the -Daptana.ruble.user.location=/User/user/Dev/aptana-studio line

Comment: It works for me with both `aptana.ruble.user.location` and `studio.rubleUserLocation`. I've read that [using quotes breaks it](http://danielsmedegaardbuus.dk/2010-08-31/be-gone-stupid-aptana-studio-3-folders-in-my-home-directory/), so try removing them.

Answer (score 5):

I am writing this incase someone else has the same problem.

### For Mac

1. Go to the **Applications** folder
2. Open the **Aptana Studio** folder
3. Right-click on the  **AptanaStudio** application icon
4. Select **Show Package Contents**
5. Open the **Contents** folder
6. Open the **MacOS** folder
7. Open the **AptanaStudio3.ini** file in your favorite text editor

And then add this line in the end

```
-Dstudio.rubleUserLocation=~/<SOME_LOCATION>/Aptana Rubles
```

Here is an example path

```
-Dstudio.rubleUserLocation=~/Documents/App Data/Aptana Rubles
```

### Make sure

1. The directory must exist
2. The directory must be writable
3. The directory must be readable

Source: [Changing Your User Bundle Path](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+User+Bundle+Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, on GNU/Linux:

In /usr/share/aptana/AptanaStudio3.ini, add the line "-Dstudio.rubleUserLocation=/home/[you]/[your_new_Rubles_directory]" (sans quotes) if it doesn't already exist.

It didn't expand "~" and instead created an empty directory in my home directory named "~" (nervously executing "rm -r \~" removed it, by the way), so I used the full path; not sure how it would respond to the location being wrapped in quotes or containing spaces, but I'd surmise it's probably fairly finicky.  This is somewhat sickeningly dirty, however, as other users of the same machine can't read or write to that hard-coded directory.